# How to pull github timeline data from BigQuery

Tags: github, google-bigquery, github-archive

I am having trouble accessing the GitHub timeline from `BigQuery`.

I was using the following query:

`SELECT repository_name, actor_attributes_company, payload_ref_type, payload_action, type, created_at FROM githubarchive:github.timeline WHERE repository_organization = 'foo' and created_at > '2014-07-01'`

and everything was working great.  Now, it looks like the githubarchive:github.timeline table is no longer available.  I've been looking around and I found another table:

`SELECT repository_name, actor_attributes_company, payload_ref_type, payload_action, type, created_at FROM publicdata:samples.github_timeline WHERE repository_organization = 'foo' and created_at > '2014-07-01'`

This query works but returns zero rows.  When I remove the created_at restriction it worked but only returned a few rows from 2012 so it looks like this is just sample data.

Does anyone know how to pull live timeline data from GitHub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `publicdata:samples.github_timeline` has only sample data.

For the real GitHub Archive documentation, look at http://www.githubarchive.org/

I wrote an article yesterday about querying it:

- https://medium.com/@hoffa/analyzing-github-issues-and-comments-with-bigquery-c41410d3308

Sample query:

```
SELECT repo.name,
       JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.action') action,
       COUNT(*) c,
FROM [githubarchive:month.201606]
WHERE type IN ('IssuesEvent')
AND repo.name IN ('kubernetes/kubernetes', 'docker/docker', 'tensorflow/tensorflow')
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

As Mikhail points out, there's also another dataset with all of GitHub's code:

- https://medium.com/@hoffa/github-on-bigquery-analyze-all-the-code-b3576fd2b150

Comment: OK, thanks.  Can you confirm that githubarchive:github.timeline has been removed?  That's really the heart of my question.

Comment: There has been some breaking changes https://medium.com/google-cloud/github-archive-fully-updated-notice-some-breaking-changes-64e7e7cd0967.

Answer (score 0):

Check out githubarchive BigQuery project
It has three datasets: day, month, year with respective daily, monthly and yearly data

Check out https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/06/GitHub-on-BigQuery-analyze-all-the-open-source-code.html for more details

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I read that article.  However, it only allows me to get historical data.  The .timeline table used to give you a full feed.  That is what I'm looking for so I can write some reports.

Comment: if you check day dataset - you will even see table with today's data that is updated hourly. and yesterday and day before etc. isn't this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  I'll take a look at re-writing the report to take the "Day" tables and compile them into a single view.  It was just easier before.  I'm not a hugely skilled SQL guy so I'm just hunting and pecking.